# How do you kill one of The Companions?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was in The Companions house and Njada was very rude too me.  It's OK to be rude in this kind of game, but I would really like to kill her.  How do I do it, so that I won't have to kill the whole town?

Should I just kill her and run?  Could I then comeback and pay some big fine?

I bet she is useless in the main story and it would be a cool role-playing thing to do.

Comment: Err, if you dislike being insulted, this is the wrong game for you.

Comment: @Domocus she remind me of someone I know and ....

Comment: @IAdapter she once reminded me of someone I knew, but then ...

Comment: @alexanderpas But then...you took an arrow to the knee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very funny way to kill her. Just cast fury on her and the people around her will kill her for you. Simple as that. Hah, I paid Athis for lessons on one-handed weapons, and leveled up my one-handed skill. Then I casted fury on him and guess what??? Everyone got out of there beds and started to kill him. I was helping kill him too, and no one came after to kill me. Hah, pretty smart. Lol.

Comment: that is very cool :D

Answer (score 13):

If you're willing to bide your time, the best bet is to finish the Companions quest line. Once you do, any member of the Companions - including Nadja - will agree to accompany you as a follower. Which means you can take her to a nice secluded shack in the middle of nowhere, and then take her out.

If you don't have the patience, or prefer a more... public method, I'll refer you to questions like [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40344/how-can-i-kill-beitrid-without-anyone-seeing). Essentially, raise your Sneak, (and optionally pickpocket or weapon) skills, wait for the right moment, and strike when nobody is looking - this will take some practice, and a bit of skill, but it's good training for the Brotherhood after all.

Comment: that would be a really evil genius thing to do(the 1st option). can I still finish the companion quest line if I kill her now? P.S. I bet you don't know, but what is your educated guess.

Comment: I don't have a save file from before completion of the chain to check, but since she's not involved in any quests, she's unlikely to be flagged as Essential.

Answer (score 11):

Complete the Companions questline, then take her as a follower and go to the [Sacellum of Boethiah](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Boethiah%27s_Calling). You need to sacrifice a companion to summon a Daedra. She sounds perfect.

Comment: i will have to find another one. my housecarl sounds like a good fit (she did say the same annoying line when I tried to used her as a storage room)

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you can get to the throat of the world.
2. Go to the VERY top. Bring her with you.
3. Fus RO DAH!!!

Answer (score 2):

I did it using sneak and arrows. The first arrow did not kill her. The Companions were mad, but I hid the bow and they relaxed.

The second shot did kill her, and I ran. I went to a guard and he said nothing.

I came back, and they are OK with me.

Answer (score 2):

After completing the companion's quest line, I took the non-essential, and quite annoying companions to the underforge and slaughtered them, 1 - it gives you a cool cutscene, and 2 - impossible to get a bounty as it is only the two of you.